# Using webview video players controls in monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, mono, xamarin.ios

I am loading a video into a webview in my monotouch iphone project.

My problem is that the iphone places the native iphone video playback controls over the video.

The controls of the webview video are not shown.

Is there a way i can disable the video playback in native broswer so i can use the customised controls of the player in my webview?

Thanks